# Delete Post by User

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, author, customization

Been trying to come up with a way to remove posts by a user when their role is changed. I am using woo subscriptions which gives a user the role subscribed when they join. However when they cancel it drops the role back to member.

Now I am trying to figure a way of removing all their posts when this happens.

I tried this

```
function auto_expire_posts( $user_id, $new_role, $old_roles ) {

        if ($new_role == 'member') {

    }

    global $wpdb;


    $update = array(
    'post_type' => 'supplier-showcase',
        'post_status' => 'trash'
    );

    $where = array(
        'post_type' => 'supplier-showcase',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => $user_id
    );

    $updated = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, $update, $where );

    }


add_action( 'set_user_role', 'auto_expire_posts', 10, 3 );
```

But It doesnt work, it will delete the users posts when ever the profile is update - role change regardless.

The I thought what about a script on the login, When users login they are directed to their account. so I thought adding

```
    <?php if( current_user_can('member')) {   
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
         $user_id = $current_user->ID;
global $wpdb;


    $update = array(
    'post_type' => 'supplier-showcase',
        'post_status' => 'trash'
'post_author' => $user_id
    );

    $where = array(
        'post_type' => 'supplier-showcase',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => $user_id
    );

    $updated = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, $update, $where );

     } ?>
```

I have also tried using a Woocommerce subscriptions hook

```
    add_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_cancelled', 10, 1);
function auto_expire_posts($subscription) {

 $user_id = get_post_meta($subscription->ID, '_customer_user', true);


    $update = array(
    'post_type' => 'supplier-showcase',
        'post_status' => 'trash'
        'post_author' => $user_id
    );

     wp_update_post( $user_id $update );
   }
```

I have been playing about with this all day, Ive got it so it works 100% when changing roles in the wordpress dashboard using the following code

```
function auto_expire_posts( $user_id, $new_role, $old_roles ) {

if ( ! in_array( subscribed', $old_roles ) ) {
return;
}

global $wpdb;

$update = array(
'post_type' => 'menu',
'post_status' => 'trash'
);

$where = array(
'post_type' => 'menu',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_author' => $user_id
);

$updated = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, $update, $where );

}

add_action( 'set_user_role', 'auto_expire_posts', 10, 3 );
```

I also found woocommerce subscriptions does not use the set_user_role hook, So I tried adding this, before my function and still doesnt work when a user cancels their subscription (found on here https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/ )

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_cancelled', 'auto_expire_posts', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting users posts upon role change](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291663/deleting-users-posts-upon-role-change)

Comment: Apologies, Removed old post. Ive been looking over this for 7 days now.

Comment: in which cases can change the role ?

Comment: When they sign up for a subscription they go to Subscribed which allows them to post into menus. If they cancel their subscription the role will change to member and their posts in menus are then deleted (menu is a custom post type)